# Installation of the com:android:support:percent:22.2.1 library fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-percent-library

Installation of the com:android:support:percent:22.2.1 library fails in Android Studio, although I have the Android Support Library and the Android Support Repository installed in the SDK Manager.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile(name:'Chart-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Common-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Data-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Feedback-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Input-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'List-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Primitives-2015.1.423-dev-release', ext:'aar')
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```

Comment: Coud you share your build.gradle file please ?

Comment: @mrd Checkout this demo for percent support library http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196553/8471798

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `com:android:support:percent:22.2.1` **doesn't exist**.

It wasn't published with the other libraries. If you check your SDK folder, you will find only the 22.2.0.

**UPDATE**
The library is now officially published with  `com:android:support:percent:28.0.0`

Comment: so this document https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Design-Support-Library#setup definitively contains an error...

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Then why am I seeing this warning - `A newer version of com.android.support.appcompat-v7 than 22.2.0 is available: appcompat-v7:22.2.1`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Because the percent library is not the appcompat library. Also while all support libraries were updated to 22.2.1, the last version of percent library is still 22.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Remember as documentation states:

> *The Android Support Library package is provided as a supplemental download to*
>   *the Android SDK and is available through the Android SDK Manager.*

You need to open the SDK Manager and at the bottom there is the "extras subtitle" and just tick the Repository for com:android:support:22.2.1. And let it download...

Then just change your gradle files as usual.

Comment: Isn't it `23.0.1` now?

Comment: It is `23.1.0` by now.

Comment: `25.1.0` or greater now

Answer (score 0):

18 May 2019, I am using the library and it is:

```
com.android.support:percent:28.0.0
```

Usage of it in (Module:app) .gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
```

Google documentation reference link is: [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#percent)